# Pamac only updates binary packages but not packages from git repositories

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

wanted to share the following problem + solution since it took me a longer time to figure this out and hope it can save you some time stumbling upon this post:

I am using Manjaro and install the following three different types of packages:

- packages which are in the main repositories and I can install them via `pacman -S`
- packages which are only in the AUR (Arch Linux User Repository) and are in binary format which can be installed via `pamac build`
- packages which are only in the AUR (Arch Linux User Repository) and have to be self-compiled (e.g. *-git packages) also via `pamac build`

Now I have had the following two issues:

- binary packages via `pamac build` have never been updated running `pacman -Syyu`
- self-compiled packages via `pamac build` have never been updated running `pacman -Syyu`

Comment: *packages which are only in the AUR (Arch Linux User Repository) and are in binary format which can be installed via pamac build* Binary packages built for arch are not automatically compatible with manjaro; as far as I know, they abandoned binary compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

So the first issues have been solved adding the following two lines to my update script:

```
pamac checkupdates -a
pamac upgrade -a
```

Where `-a` stands for **AUR**

I had this for a longer time in my script and it has been working fine and I thought I was done since now all packages installed via pacman have been updated via `pacman -Syyu` and all packages from AUR have been updated via the above commmand.

I was wondering though, why the `*-git` packages I installed (which had frequent updates on the master / main branch) were never updated.

So I dug into the issue and had to adapt my script to the following:

```
pamac checkupdates -a --devel
pamac upgrade -a --devel
```

Where `--devel` includes development packages (like `*-git`).

Now I could notice that running this command takes way longer checking for updates, since `-a` just checks the packages in the AUR if they are newer (fast) but if the is a `*-git` package and there was no update in AUR but only in the git repository, it would not pick it up.

The new command including `--devel` however, took way longer, since it was asking first AUR for updates (quick) + for development packages it was also asking the repository in the back to check if there have been any updates.

Now finally I can keep all packages up-to-date with this simple script:

```
pacman -Syyu
pamac checkupdates -a --devel
pamac upgrade -a --devel
```